# ADC sampling time longer than expected

Tags: adc, sampling, time-constant

I have noticed an unexpected behavior with the ADC of a STM32l0 microcontroller on one of my projects. I’m trying to read 3 channels as fast as I can. My signal is buffered with an OPA127 op-amp that has an output impedance of 60 Ω. According to the datasheet of the STM32, the ADC’s sampling switch resistor is 1 kΩ, and the sampling capacitor 8 pF (both are maximal values). This leads to a charging time constant of 8 ns, and I would expect to be able to sample quite fast (say 1-10 MHz).

The sampling time can be set to different values, and I have experimented with different settings until the value returned by the ADC is correct. Surprisingly, I need to use 79.5 cycles or more to get the correct value. Anything faster returns a value that is lower than expected. The ADC clock is 16 MHz, so 79.5 cycles take 5us, i.e. much longer than what I would expect (~50 ns). That’s a difference of 2 orders of magnitudes.

I’m currently testing with a constant voltage. But I’m reading 3 channels, two are at zero volts and 1 is at Vref/2. As the 3 channels are polled one after the other, the sampling capacitor is at 0 V before it needs to read the channel with Vref/2. Still I would expect to charge the sampling capacitor in a few 10 s of ns.

I have most likely overlooked something obvious, and would welcome any tips on what I should check.

Comment: Does the ADC have multiple channels, or does it have one ADC that it switches between channels?

Comment: How is the op-amp output connected to ADC input pin? If directly, will the op-amp work stably when there is a capacitor being switched to the output at high rate?

Comment: Don’t conflate sampling time with conversion time. Depending on the actual stm32 part, 5us is not unreasonable for an adc conversion. 50ns conversion would imply the adc does 20Msps and it won’t do that with a 16MHz clock. What is the actual STM32 part number? What does the datasheet say about the ADC performance? [edit] stm3210 is the board number. The cpu is a STM32F103. These have an average performance ADC, so 5us is not unreasonable.

Comment: To answer the comments: @JRE - It's a single ADC switching between channels. I'm reading 3 channels, 2 are currently at 0V, so the sampling cap will be at 0V when the ADC switched to reading the channel that is at ~1.65V. 
Justme - Directly from the output to the ADC pin. I'll check with a scope later today.
Kartman - Indeed. Conversion time is an additional 12.5 cycles after the sampling. I'm using stm32l083czt6.